# Filezilla/Wildfly server deployment error (Possible database dependencies)

Tags: database, dependencies, wildfly, filezilla, myeclipse

This is my first time on here. I am having an issue deploying a java application I made on myEclipse. I am using Filezilla to host my Wildfly 9.0.2 test server. I exported my project to a .war file and upon dragging it into the test server I am met with a deployment.failed. Upon viewing the file in Notepad it declares "Services with missing/unavailable dependencies". one such error can be seen below:

[ "jboss.naming.context.java.module.myproject.myproject.env.common.jdbc.database_connection is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.database.connection] "

There are five of these similar errors and all point to a diffferent database connection of some type that I am not using within my project. I understand the issue but I do not know where these dependencies are declared and how I can go about removing them.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Creating the WAR file will use the project's deployment assembly (assuming you're using MyEclipse 2013 or later). Right click on the project and select Properties. Then go to the MyEclipse/Deployment Assembly page. This will have all of the files that are added to the deployment (or to the WAR file).

However, the message seems to suggest that a project is using a database connection which can't be found when running on the server. A first thought was that you're using the inbuilt Derby database but don't have that running when you run on Wildfly.But you say that you're not using a database. Also, I'm not familiar with how Filezilla can host a J2EE server - I thought Filezilla was an FTP client and server solution. Perhaps you could give more details, if this answer doesn't help.

Comment: I am relatively new to Java and my terminology may be off. I used your advise and it didn't state any instances of where these database connections are declared. I think that is the main issue. Somewhere in my code it has stated that database connection x,y,z is necessary when I only need x. So what I want to do is remove y and z so I can deploy my test project. Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's not enough information to try to guess where the references might be. You'll have to go through your code to see where you might be referencing a connection or check your configuration for data sources in WildFly. Documentation is here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/DataSource+configuration